# How to add a pop-up window to Magento 2 front page?

Tags: popup

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto
13 Amasty extensions
```

I have done a composer update and updated my Amasty extensions yesterday and this destroyed the Newsletter pop-up that is built into the Smartwave Porto theme. The reason this is a problem is - I don't really use it for Newsletter sign-up at all -> I modified it and use the Newsletter pop-up to post special messages around holidays (I need it for Christmas now). The issue with it is that it appears invisible with just a red X.

I don't think this is something I can fix myself so I raised it to Smartwave Porto but they haven't come back to me yet.

**Is there another easy to install and use pop-up solution I could use to put up a Christmas message to visitors of my site?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside your theme add below file in path
   **app\design\frontend\your\theme\Magento_Cms\layout\cms_index_index.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Magento_Cms::popup.phtml"></block>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
   ```
2. And Inside your theme add below file in path
   **app\design\frontend\your\theme\Magento_Cms\templates\popup.phtml**

   ```
   <div id="popup" style="display: none;">
   <h2>Your massage</h2>
   </div>
   <script>require(['jquery','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'],
   function (
       $,
       modal
   ) {
       var modaloption = {
           type: 'popup',
           modalClass: 'my-popup',
           responsive: true,
           innerScroll: true,
           title: 'My Modal',
           buttons: []
       };
       var callforoption = modal(modaloption, $('#popup'));
       $('#popup').modal('openModal');
   } );   </script>
   ```